# How can I make a two column table of contents

Tags: libreoffice-writer

If I select two columns in the Table of Contents window, they overlap and I got the result below:

[image]

I already tried setting manual tab stops, but then if doesn't go up to the right end of the column and I get something like:

```
Title 1....5
Title 2....10
Title 3....105
```

Comment: For your tab stop, you need to set it to Right Aligned, the little backwards`L` shape.

Comment: I done that, but it doesnt seem to work with tab stops from the paragraph style, it only work when setting the tab value in the table of contents setting window. And there there isn't a choice of right aligned.

Comment: I think my document is somehow corrupted. If I created a new file, Load all the styles from my file and import the whole document, the table of contents is created nicely.